# How to redirect stderr and stdout into /var/log directory in background process?

Tags: python, redirect

With the below command ,all  stderr and stdout  redirect into /tmp/ss.log and it perform in background process.

```
python  sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json  > /tmp/ss.log   2>&1 &
```

Now to redirect stderr and stdout into /var/log directory as following.

```
python  sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json  > /var/log/ss.log   2>&1 &
bash: /var/log/ss.log: Permission denied
```

It  encounter permission problem.
I made a try with sudo tee as following.

```
python  sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json  |sudo tee -a /var/log/ss.log   2>&1 &
python  sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json  2>&1|sudo tee -a /var/log/ss.log  &
nohup python  sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json  |sudo tee -a /var/log/ss.log   2>&1 &
nohup python  sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json  2>&1|sudo tee -a /var/log/ss.log  &
```

All of them encounter another problem,the command can't run in background process,it run as foreground process.

How  to redirect stderr and stdout into /var/log directory in background process?

Comment: your `2>&1` should come before the `|`

Comment: nohup is for backgrounding processes

Comment: python  sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json  2>&1 |sudo tee -a /var/log/ss.log   &

Comment: iit is nouse to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/ss.service

[Unit]
Description=ss

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/python sslocal -c /etc/ss.json > /var/log/ss.log 2>&1'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To start it after editing the config file.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable ss.service
sudo systemctl start ss.service
sudo systemctl status ss -l
```

1.ss run as a service and it start in reboot automatically.
2.ss can write log into /var/log/ss.log without permission problem.

Answer (score 3):

Although you try to redirect `stdout` / `stderr` using bash redirection, I may add another alternative: **Redirect within your code**:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(stdout.log, 'w')
sys.stderr = open(stderr.log, 'w')
```

You just need to execute this code during application startup and all the output (`stdout`, and `stderr`) will be written to the defined log files.

Answer (score 2):

Just invoke the redirection as root:

```
sudo sh -c 'python  sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json  > /var/log/ss.log   2>&1' &
```

Comment: `\var\log\` owner is `system` and can't write any unregistered user. Another point how handle log errors (overflow,duplicate,lock etc.)?  User app run under user directory if not an service, if a service try register to system(systemd, init.d). Question is wrong, need replace to "How to start a service with external trigger ?"